Is there an alternative to showing multiple error snack bars?
I'm working on the UI/UX design of a complex cloud-bases platform (enterprise type), and there's a case in which we must show to the user that there are several errors that he needs to fix before moving forward with the flow. Sometimes users can get up to 15 stacked errors. Today, we're displaying them as stacked snack bars, here's a low-fidelity wireframe:

The client and user's petition is for us to not hide these messages, since they need to be addressed by the user. Are there alternatives that are friendlier and more intuitive?

Your client is correct. I'd never hide those messages, especially if they require client's interaction.
However, if messages pile up, then you'll have other issues, including cognitive load, system overwhelming and even messages that may not be visible simply because they don't fit.
So you could go with something like this:

and on click:

Depending on the developer's needs, the type of message, and user testing, you may need to show older messages first. I'm showing the newer messages first (which is the default for snackbars), but if you read the text, you'll see I mention "the one that started it all." What I try to convey with that is: maybe fixing only one thing will fix all subsequent issues.
